# how read div atributes that changed by javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have written a javascript code that changed the value attribute of a div tag in html page, on other hand in a button click event (when webpage post-backed to server) in asp.net i want to read the attribute value of this div tag

my html div tag

```
<div id="t1" class="Gozineha" runat="server" >
```

my asp.net code:

```
 string s = t1.Attributes["value"];
```

and my javascript code is

```
   $(".Gozineha button").click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    val = $this.attr("value");
    $this.parent().attr("value", val);
    sib = $this.siblings();
    sib.attr("class", "btn btn-default btn-xs");
    //sib.removeAttr("value");
});
```

please help me how read the atribute value of this div tag in asp.net

Comment: did you use div with runat="server" then only you can access it on serverside

Comment: yes i did, i first change using javascript then in a button click when  a gain form is post-backed , i want read atribute value

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this in aspx code:

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        t1.RenderControl(h);
        string str = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

In str You will get content of your div.